# Can I use a language other than JavaScript in client-side scripting?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, coffeescript

I know that IE could run VBScript and JScript, but I want cross-browser things that use another language than JavaScript, so that I wrote this:

```
 <script src='bla.rb' type='text/ruby'></script>
 <script src='bla.coffee' type='text/coffescript'></script>
 <script src='bla.ics' type='text/icedcoffescript'></script>
```

It would run normally. How to make these tags works?

Comment: What is your question then?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there were browsers that you could install new languages in, but if you're looking for a cross-browser solution, then no, you're stuck with Javascript.

Comment: @MrLister you could install a language interpreter through Javascript. Javascript is perfectly capable of parsing Ruby.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180092/dart-vm-foreign-browsers-non-google/14180465#14180465

Comment: @JanDvorak Yeah, I was just thinking, wasn't the Coffeescrpt interpreter written in JS? So maybe there's hope after all.

Comment: @MrLister I thought coffeescript was compiled server-side to javascript?

Comment: microsoft's silverlight allows you to run Ruby and Python in the browser as far as I remember.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot rely on the presence of any of these other languages in the majority of browsers. You can potentially ask a user to instal a new language or plugin, but JavaScript is the only 'universal' client-side scripting language.

Answer (score 3):

Python can be used if you compile CPython to JavaScript using [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten). Maybe you can do the same with Ruby.

Besides Emscripten, there are languages that compile to JavaScript, such as [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) and [Fay](http://fay-lang.org/). You could also write your own VM in JavaScript and write a compiler for your favourite language that targets that VM, of course.

In the end, the browser itself can only interpret JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby: [Maybe?](http://www.ironruby.net/browser/) Not sure how far along this project is, but it does exist.

(Iced)CoffeeScript: [Yes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170473/is-there-a-way-to-send-coffeescript-to-the-clients-browser-and-have-it-compiled) But you have to load one additional JavaScript file as the CoffeeScript compiler.

Comment: I am amused, surprised, and horrified. Revised appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

There are many [languages that can be compiled into JavaScript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/list-of-languages-that-compile-to-js), including C, C++, Python, PHP, and several others.

There are also several implementations of virtual machines for other languages in JavaScript, including [DoppioJVM](http://plasma-umass.org/doppio-demo/) for JVM languages and [JSIL](http://jsil.org/) for .NET programming languages.